# Split table row into two rows

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to split a table row into two rows instead of using nested tables?

It's what I want:

[image: my table]

`td #4` should has full width and I don't know is there any **CSS** trick or anything to do this or not.

**NOTE:** I do not want to use another `<tr>` with `colspan`. I want it inside the same row **within** other `<td>`s, because I'm using [striped table](https://getuikit.com/docs/table).

Comment: Is `colspan` not going to work for you? So td#4 has `colspan=3`

Comment: I want `td#4` inside the row within other `tds`.

Comment: It will look that way if you use css to manage the heights...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you updated your question, another way you can do is to use nested `div` elements, with `display: table-cell;` properties

```
.top_row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.top_row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9bYTh/1/)

> Note: Yes, you can `float` the `div` as well, which I will prefer more
>   over here, with a self clearing `class` but I used `display:
>   table-cell;` so it will retain the properties like `vertical-align:
>   middle;` which you may need as you are using `table`

---

Why not use [`colspan`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/td/colspan) for this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9bYTh/)

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Merged</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Note: Am using `border` and `width` attributes here just for
>   demonstration purpose, consider declaring a `class` and style it using
>   CSS

Comment: Since I'm using striped table http://www.getuikit.com/docs/table.html this wont work.

Comment: @Maysam This is like taking out a new condition each time user updates his answer, can you specify all the do's and dont's in your question? would be really helpful to figure out what you really need, also, I guess you didn't read my updated answer

Comment: Sorry but I explained clearly in the question. I want all them in the same row.

Comment: @Maysam aren't they in the same row now in my updated answer?

Comment: Yes they are, I did not saw the demo at first.

Comment: @Maysam As expected :)

Comment: One problem with this is it seems semantically incorrect. it feels like each item in the data set should be a single row (tr), not spanning two rows per item. The fact that it looks like two rows is only a detail in the presentation.

Also, what if you want to wrap the double-row in a container, for doing things like hover effects over the entire thing?

I suppose there's probably no ideal solution that satisfies everything.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check at this code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/rg0dk576/
```

HTML

```
<table class='normal' border="1" width="100%">
<caption> This is a normal table look&feel </caption>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>

</table>

<br>

<table class='multirow' border="1" width="100%">
<caption> This is the same table with rows splitted into multiple rows, only by using CSS </caption>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

td:nth-child(even) { background-color: #0000AA22; }

tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: lightgreen; }

.multirow td { display: inline-block !important; width: auto; border: 1px solid #eee; }

.multirow td:nth-child(1), 
.multirow td:nth-child(2), 
.multirow td:nth-child(3) { width: 33%; }
.multirow td:nth-child(4) { width: 100%; }
.multirow td:nth-child(5), 
.multirow td:nth-child(6) { width: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jQuery to do all this. See the fiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E2sKV/)

HTML code here:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>a
        </td>
        <td>b
        </td>
        <td>c
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>a2
        </td>
        <td>b2
        </td>
        <td>c2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="b1">click here</button>
```

And a jQuery handler like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#b1').on('click',function(){
        var v=$('</tr><tr id="row11" colspan=3><td>text</td>'); 
        $('#row1').after(v);});
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't work: the newly appended row doesn't take the whole three columns, just expands column 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a `<table/>` into the cell you want to split:

```
<html>
<body>
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Age</th> 
    <th>City</th> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>John Doe</td> 
    <td>35</td> 
    <td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>New York</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Los Angeles</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>Alias Calvo</td> 
    <td>25</td> 
    <td>Los Angeles</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>Jane Smith</td> 
    <td>30</td> 
    <td>Chicago</td> 
  </tr> 
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```